# Cakephp find data from other Model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Model `Model1` that is in no way connected to `Model2` but because `Model2` has a some data i need in my `Controller1` i need to access the data of `Model2`

Is this possible with cake? and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but assuming you can get the data from the Controller, just use:

```
// Model1sController
$this->loadModel('Model2');
$this->Model2->find('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your model to the $uses property of the controller. Then you can access the model from the controller by $this->MyModel